# Golang - use two Reader returned lines for select statement

Tags: select, go, client, chat

For a simple golang chat/telnet client, I want to pass strings received from two bufio Readers to a select statement, so I can either send the user input to the server, or print the server sent data.

```
conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8998")
for {
    select{
    case line, _ := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n'):
        fmt.Print("> ")
        fmt.Fprintf(conn, line + "\n")
    case data, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n'):
        fmt.Print(data)
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me back this error

```
select case must be receive, send or assign recv
```

I suspect I should be using channels. But

```
conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8998")
outgoing := make(chan string)
incoming := make(chan string)
for {
    inputReader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    connReader := bufio.NewReader(conn)

    o, _ := inputReader.ReadString('\n')
    i, _ := connReader.ReadString('\n')
    outgoing <- o
    incoming <- i

    select{
    case out := <-outgoing:
        fmt.Print("> ")
        fmt.Fprintf(conn, out + "\n")
    case in := <-incoming:
        fmt.Print(in)
    }
}
```

But the code doesn't accept or receive data. Finally, I suspect I should be using two go routines to check for the Reader return value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run them in goroutines or they can't simultaneously occur:

```
conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8998")

// Make outgoing reader routine
outgoing := make(chan string)
go func() {
    inputReader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        o, err := inputReader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("outgoing error: %v", err)
            return
        }
        outgoing <- o
    }
}()

// Make incoming reader routine
incoming := make(chan string)
go func() {
    connReader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    for {
        i, err := connReader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("incoming error: %v", err)
            return
        }
        incoming <- i
    }
}()

for {
    select {
    case out := <-outgoing:
        fmt.Print("> ")
        fmt.Fprintf(conn, out+"\n")
    case in := <-incoming:
        fmt.Print(in)
    }
}
```

### Edit

To further elaborate: your first example won't work because `select` requires each case to be either a channel read or channel send operation, and the function call `bufio.Reader.ReadString()` is neither.

Your second example won't work because the line `outgoing <- o` will block indefinitely.  It is trying to send `o` over the channel `outgoing`, but `outgoing` is not buffered, and nothing is listening on it.  Furthermore, since neither `ReadString()` call will return until a line is read, your `for` loop will only proceed once a line is read from *BOTH* readers in turn (and will then block on the channel send).

That's why you need each Reader to have its own goroutine, so each can independently read off its Reader as input allows, and store it to the relevant channel as lines are read, and your `select` statement can then react to each line as it comes in from the individual goroutines.

Comment: You put the goroutines outside of the for loop. Does this mean that the goroutines don't close? And the channel continuously gets filled as if it was a for loop? When I wrote this out, the client works only  if I put the goroutines in the for loop.

Comment: Well, there's no need to recreate the goroutines on each loop iteration, as that would also involve recreating the readers, and you'd leave a lot of orphaned routines behind.  Note that the goroutines shown have a for loop within them, so they loop endlessly, filling the channel as the Reader reads.  If you want to close them, the optimal way is to use a quit channel that all 3 (the two goroutines and the main routine) listen to, and abort their for loops (generally via `return`) when that quit channel is closed.  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/vxK6kU21Ya

Comment: Thanks @Kaedys a very nice example of how to work around and use channels for blocking routines.